# composer conflicts symfony/framework-bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to compile a Symfony 2.5 application, and I'm getting this conflict with symfony/symfony and symfony/framework-bundle. I've tried to downgrade doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle to 3.0.x-dev, aloso tried with the version 3.3.0 but require PHP 8.

Any idea on which version of doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle I should use?

Thanks

```
- Root composer.json requires doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.2,0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.2.0].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.2 (conflict analysis result)
...
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
- doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.3|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.3.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.45].
- Only one of these can be installed: symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.45, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.12], symfony/symfony[v2.5.0, ..., v2.5.12]. symfony/symfony replaces symfony/framework-bundle and thus cannot coexist with it.
```

Comment: Symfony 2.5 is horribly outdated. You should update that, to be able to install current packages. Also, what's the command you are currently calling? Do you try to install the FixturesBundle for that application for the first time?

Comment: Have you tried faking the PHP version via platform configuration? No guarantee this works but at least you might be able to compile some vendor folder with matching requirements. Perhaps try on the command-line only first. And yes, Symfony does not offer good backwards compatibility so check an upgrade path, too. What NicoHaase wrote basically.  --- in case you wondered why I close-voted: You need to provide more details specific to the situation, not just that there is a conflict in the dependencies IMHO, which is just the matter of fact.

Comment: @hakre faking the PHP version won't work if the packages itself are not compatible with each other.

Comment: @NicoHaase: Yes, true. Wishful thinking on my end, a better suggestion may have been the prefer-lowest argument anyway. But still if there is no installable set, composer can only state the fact (and likely composer is already looking for that IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle#3.2.0) specs for that version, you cannot do that.

Version 3.2.0 of the package requires:

```
php: ^7.1
doctrine/data-fixtures: ^1.3
doctrine/doctrine-bundle: ^1.6
doctrine/orm: ^2.6.0
symfony/doctrine-bridge: ~3.4|^4.1
symfony/framework-bundle: ^3.4|^4.1
```

Note the `symfony/framework-bundle` line.

The highest you can go is **version 2.3.0**.

Are you sure that this is not a typo (3.2.0 vs 2.3.0)?

Comment: That an existing project I've taken, with the version 3.2.0. I tried to run composer install from the composer.lock and it seem to work. But now I have this error `code Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() must be an instance of Composer\Script\CommandEvent, instance of Composer\Script\Event given,`

Comment: That looks like a different error - it could be related to Composer itself. Maybe the package you want to use is not compatible with Composer v2?